# Capture full webView in android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am unable to capture complete `WebView`, I'm capturing only visible content of Dashboard(Activity). My `WebView` is exceeding the activity. Guide me how to capture complete view.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url) {
        webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), webView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        webView.draw(canvas);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url) {
        Picture picture = v.capturePicture();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                      picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
        picture.draw(canvas);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);      
}
```

Sorry, I did not notice this

> This method was deprecated in API level 19.
>   Use onDraw(Canvas) to obtain a bitmap snapshot of the WebView, or saveWebArchive(String) to save the content to a file.
>
> Gets a new picture that captures the current contents of this WebView. The picture is of the entire document being displayed, and is not limited to the area currently displayed by this WebView. Also, the picture is a static copy and is unaffected by later changes to the content being displayed.

Comment: provided code capturing view part and showing white space in borders :@ Radu Ionescu